# Not able to find Element in Appium By.name in dropdown with search list

Tags: java, selenium, appium, uiautomatorviewer

I am totally new on Appium,want to find element By.name,while doing that I am searching from list so getting result of search text matching,but its not clicking Exact name matching element even it is not clicking any element from list,may be its trying to click Text typed. Don't know how to apply multiple condition to find element.So how can we do that ? attached image related to this:

1)Image:1
[image]

2)Image:2

[image]
`driver.findElement(By.name("Biscuit")).click();`

Comment: biscuit is listed as non clickable on the element details, maybe if some element above the hierarchy is, you can writ to click on that element with a child with text "Biscuit"

Comment: @juhlia I have updated screenshot,I am totally new on appium, cant we search element with multiple condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use xpath to apply more condition to find element even in appium too,for above case used 2nd Image & applied condition as 
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Biscuit']")).click();`

so we achieve it with two condition

1.className="android.widget.TextView" and text='Biscuit'

notice that clickable=false still it doesn't matter, it click clickable Parent

for more details: http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/10/ui-automator-viewer-get-android-app.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all element in the product list have same id. So, You can find all elements in the product list and then using the for loop iterate through each element.

```
List<WebElement> productList = driver.findElements(By.id("producttext"));

    for(WebElement product : productList) {
        String productText = product.getText();

        if(productText.equalsIgnoreCase("Biscuit")) {
            product.click();
        }
    }
```

The above code will store all items with id "producttext" present on the current screen. And the for loop will iterate through each element. I have added a check that when it finds element with text "Biscuit", it will click that element. You can add more check depending on your test.